# .desktop file supported on which operating systems?

Tags: linux, unix, desktop

On which operating systems can we use the .desktop file from unix / linux?

Is there a list of operating systems which support and use it?
Do they all use he same syntax, settings and properties or are there big differences between the operating systems?

Answer (score 1):

It should work in most, if not all XServer based UIs: [Anatomy of a .desktop File « The Linux Critic](http://linuxcritic.wordpress.com/2010/04/07/anatomy-of-a-desktop-file/)

They are based on [a Freedesktop.org standard](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/), so at the very least GNOME and KDE. Any server system that supports X and GNOME will support .Desktop files.